# Program wil only print first variable in list python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, input

This is my code:

```
H = Waterstof = 1.008
He = Helium = 4.003

atomen = [H, He]

vraag = raw_input("Welke atoommassa wil je weten? \n")

for vraag in atomen:
    print vraag
    break
```

I've not included all the atoms to make sure it's not too big for you guys to read.

So the problem is that my output is always 1.008 (the mass of H) even when I enter He as input.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over `[H, He]` and printing the first variable; the `break` ends your loop so the second value never gets printed.

Rather than use separate variables and a list, use a dictionary:

```
atom_weights = {'H': 1.008, 'He': 4.003}
```

This allows you to print the correct atom weight *for the given atom abbreviation*:

```
print atom_weights[vraag]
```

If you wanted to support full names too, you'll have to map those too:

```
atom_names = {'waterstof': 'H', 'helium': 'He'}
```

This maps lowercased names to the symbol, so you can first check if the user entered a full name and map that to the symbol:

```
symbol = atom_names.get(vraag.lower(), vraag)
```

This translates `Waterstof` to `waterstof`, and finds `H`. If the name is not present it is assumed that the user entered the symbol instead.

Comment: It's not related to the problem at all, looping trough a list `atomen` in this case is perfectly valid, `break` is the problem.

Comment: @iharob: perhaps it is because I can read the dutch, but the user is trying to find the atom mass for the given input. `vraag` is **reused** in the loop.

Comment: @iharob: the loop is a **red herring**.

Comment: @iharob OP wants to get the related number (for example the mass of atom ) based on he's input!!!

Answer (score 0):

You re-use `vraag` and then break in the first iteration of the loop
This should work:

```
H = Waterstof = 1.008
He = Helium = 4.003

atomen = [H, He]

vraag = raw_input("Welke atoommassa wil je weten? \n")

for v in atomen:
    if v==vraag:
        print vraag
        break
```

However, for a better solution to your actual problem I would probably use a dictionary (see Martijn Pieters's answer)